# How to align the Label in UITableview?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, ios4, ios-simulator

I'm having a `UITableView` in which I have images of different size. So when I am running the program I am getting different starting point of label in TableView.

I want all the labels to start from same point.

Alignment is not working for me. I want all label to start from certain distance from left.

Is there any solution for that?

Comment: are you using custom cell of TableView? if not use customcell

Comment: please read tutorials about customcell of TableView

Comment: ok thanks i think custom call worked.. thanks a lot..

Comment: upvote my comment people will know the answer

Answer (score 0):

Derive a class from UITableViewCell.

Override the method `layoutSubviews`. In this method set proper frames for all the components like imageview, primary label etc.

CustomCell.h

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
{

}

@end
```

CustomCell.m

```
@implementation CustomCell

    -(void) layoutSubviews
    {
         [super layoutSubviews];
        self.imageView.frame = SOME_FRAME;
        self.textLabel.frame = SOME_OTHER_FRAME;

    }

@end
```

Now instead of creating the cells from UITableViewCell in cellForRowAtIndexPath, use above cell.

Comment: hey friends this link helped me in solving my problem.. <http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/> you can also try it

Answer (score 0):

ur label position is disturbed because of the image ?

if yes then there are 2 ways to do it 
1

> [imgView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill]

2 you should first get the width of the image view and then add some space factor and then set the appropriate starting point for your uilabel.

```
UILabel *lbl = ...;
UIImageView * imgView = ....;
CGRect lblFrame = lbl.frame;
lblFrame.origin.x = imgView.frame.origin.x + imgView.frame.size.width + 10;
[lbl setFrame:lblFrame];
```

EDIT:

if resizing the uiimage is not a problem then resize your image...

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage; }
```

> Blockquote

```
> [CLASSNAME imageWithImage:yourImage scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(50,50)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, its very useful to align the UILabel in UiTableView:
UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]init];

```
    label.frame=CGRectMake(80, 2, 180, 60);

    label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    label.text=[ShopListOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    label.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

    label.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];

    label.numberOfLines=2;

    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
```